# XPath to exclude certain XML elements?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have now read many (maybe all) posts on excluding elements in XPath and I just do not get this working. I have no clue why.

Let's say I have the following structure:

```
<root>
  <elemA>
      Hello World!
  </elemA>
  <elemB>
      This is awesome!
      <elemC>Really!</elemC>
  </elemB>
</root>
```

No I want all elements except `elemC`.

Based on what I have read, I tried the following XPath:

**Option 1:**

```
//*[not(self::elemC)]
```

**Option 2:**

```
//*[not(name()='elemC')]
```

**Option 3:**

```
//*[name()!='elemC']
```

I have no clue why this is not working, but suspect some stupid mistake. If I do the exact opposite (i.e. leaving out the `not` or `!`) the XPath correctly selects the `elemC` element.

The result should be this:

```
<root>
  <elemA>
      Hello World!
  </elemA>
  <elemB>
      This is awesome!
  </elemB>
</root>
```

Comment: This is a well-expressed question that touches upon a class of problems that XPath (alone) cannot solve.  See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39640786/290085) for further details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**XPath is for selection.  What you want to select does not exist in your XML document.**

You need another tool such as **XSLT** to generate an XML output document based on an input XML document.  XSLT can generate your desired output trivially via the identity transformation supplemented with a simple template that suppresses the copying of the element that you do not want (`elemC`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="elemC"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XPath alone cannot help you.**

Comment: Thanks a lot. That really helped to clarify. Wondering why I always understood the other questions regard "exclude element x with XPath" to mean the same I meant. Anyway, I will try XSLT. Does not seem to be too complicated, once one knows what tool to use.

Comment: You can certainly exclude nodes from a list of otherwise selected nodes, but you cannot select an `elemB` without a child `elemC` because no such `elemB` exists in your XML.