# A complex xpath with exclusion

Tags: xpath

I am trying to extract an xpath with an exclusion but not able to work this.

```
 (//div[@class='row site country-names']/following-sibling::div)[1]/div
```

The above xpath extracts all three divs, however i need to exclude the div which has a dot seperator.
[image]

I tried for the exception and not however it does not work.

```
 (//div[@class='row site country-names']/following-sibling::div)[1]/div and not [@class='dot-seperator']
```

Comment: Or even better: Provide a url.

Comment: No, a URL isn't better, because the chances are this question will be on SO long after the URL has gone dead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath to exclude certain XML elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39640487/xpath-to-exclude-certain-xml-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `not` to exclude any attribute, for example for class:

```
//div[@class='row site country-names']/following-sibling::div[not(@class)]
```

Use @ with the attribute name:

`[not(@attribute_name)]`

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are trying to select a node while excluding one of its children.

The result of your XPath expression does not include the div with class "dot-separator". However it does include its parent div, and in many cases applications that use XPath to select nodes treat it as selecting the entire subtree rooted at that node. It's the calling application that chooses to do that, not XPath itself.